# React-Redux not saving state and always returning initial values

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, gatsby

in my mock up application (no back-end) written with Gatsby, I have two components displaying elements from the same list of objects. My objects are threads of conversations, so the first component is only displaying the titles of the threads and the second a long list of all the messages in all threads.
I would like to be able to select a thread in the first component, such that the second only displays the conversations that belong to that thread. 
So, following the pattern that I have already been using in other parts of my code, I now have the following:

reducers.js

```
...
const activeConversation = (state = {id : -1, name: "none"}, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CONVERSATION:

      //I have tried all possible variations I could think of the following

      let newstate = action.payload.state;
      state.id = newstate.id;
      state.name = newstate.name;

     //also tried to directly return action.payload.state and state
      return newstate; 
    default:
      return state
  }
}
...
const rootReducer = combineReducers({activeConversation, /*more here*/})
export default rootReducer;
```

my action is defined as:

```
import {SET_CONVERSATION} from "./preferences";

export default function setConversation(state){
  return {
      type: SET_CONVERSATION,
      payload: {
        state
     }

}

}
```

and I am dispatching with the following:

```
let [conversation, saveConversation] = React.useState("0");

const setConversation = (event) => {
    saveConversation(event.currentTarget.id);
    let selected = {
        id: conversation,
        name: toString(conversation)
    }
    props.dispatch(actionSetConversation(selected));
  }
}
```

I have verified that the dispatch call is being executed correctly, but accessing the stored value from the second component always returns the initial value. 
Any idea? I have been using this identical pattern on other components on my code, so I'm really very confused and out of ideas.

Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to determine if the flow of data is correct but I see an error code here.

```
switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CONVERSATION: {
      let newstate = action.payload.state;

      return {
        ...state,
        id: newstate.id,
        name: newstate.name
      }
    }

    default:
      return state
  }
```

You can't directly reasign a value with `=` because Redux works with inmmutable data. This means that a state can only be replaced with a new object, and it cannot be altered.

For more information check this link:

https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles

Comment: thanks @nicnoniahi. I had already  tried this but it's not solving my problem. the problem must be somewhere else and I am trying to figure out what else could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

try the below -
create a copy of the existing redux state -
out the many copy methods available, you can use.

```
let newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
newState.id = action.payload.state.id;
newState.name = action.payload.state.name;
return newState;
```

you can use object destructing too.

Comment: thanks @user2063635. I had already tried this but it's not solving my problem. the problem must be somewhere else and I am trying to figure out what else could be wrong